# How much time left to given date (days, hours, mins, s.)

Tags: python, time, clock, difference

I'm trying to make some kind of "deadline clock" in python.
There is lot of topics about time difference calculations and I followed some and put together this kind of code:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# Get current time:
today = datetime.date.today()
timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
current_time = str(today) + " " + str(timenow.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

# Set deadline:
deadline = "2019-12-12 15:00:00"

# Calculate difference:
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ends = datetime.datetime.strptime(deadline, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
diff = relativedelta(ends, start)

print("Now: " + current_time)
print("Deadline: " + deadline)

print(str(diff.days) + " days. " 
      + str(diff.hours) + " hours. " 
      + str(diff.minutes) + " minutes. " 
      + str(diff.seconds) + " seconds. " 
      )
```

But the problem is, that it will allways show just maximum of one month difference... So where is the problem?

Comment: You're not showing the months or years from the relativedelta? You may be confusing it with the standard library timedelta.

Answer (score 1):

Just substract your start date with the end date.

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
deadline = "2019-12-12 15:00:00"
current_time = str(today) + " " + str(timenow.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ends = datetime.datetime.strptime(deadline, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(start - ends)
```

As suggested in the comments, you don't really need to to use both `.today()` and `.now()` separately, `.now()` returns the current date and time as a datetime object itself.

```
import datetime
timenow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
deadline = "2019-12-12 00:00:00"
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(timenow,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ends = datetime.datetime.strptime(deadline, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(start - ends)
```

Comment: i don't knwo why you use `today()` if `now()` gives you date and time. You don't have to convert it to string and then parse it back. `start = datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: I just copied the OP's code and added the required changes. You are right though, I should add this. Thank you.

Comment: BTW: to remove microsecond you can do `start = start.replace(microsecond = 0)`

Comment: ok, now I see that OP used this method.  I skiped code in question and I started at code in answer :)