# How to find difference between two timestamps in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I need to find the difference between two timestamps in minutes. 
I am using Python 3.6.

Here is my script:

```
import datetime
from dateutil import parser

indate = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
indate2 = parser.parse(indate)
indate3  = indate2.date()
intime = indate2.time()


outdate1 = "2019-10-16T06:38:55.000+0000"
outdate2 = parser.parse(outdate1)
outdate3  = outdate2.date()
outtime = outdate2.time()

### ---THEN  PRINT DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THE TWO IN MINUTES --- ###
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much time left to given date (days, hours, mins, s.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391143/how-much-time-left-to-given-date-days-hours-mins-s)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between two dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

It will be advisable to ensure that they both have the same timezone:

```
 (indate2.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc) - outdate2).total_seconds()/60
    Out[161]: 494.60840941666663
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the timezone awarenes from outdate2

```py
print(indate2 - outdate2.replace(tzinfo=None))
```